# command exited with status 1: pager -s

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, pager, manpage

I'm running Ubuntu on Android. Everything was fine, now i got a issue, i guess i broke something..But I don't have a clue what it could be.

When I try something like `$ man something` e.g. `man grep` i get an error

```
man: command exited with status 1: pager -s
```

and the man page stops after the first page.

I figured out that `$ less filename` isn't working anymore how it should only the first page is displayed no navigation possible anymore.

`vim` and `more` are working fine...

Any kind of ideas are welcome.

```
# type pager
pager is hashed (/usr/bin/pager)
```

Reinstallation didn't help.

Comment: Do you have `devtmpfs` mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and re-installing `less`.

```
apt-get remove less
apt-get install less
```